# hyperledger fabric couchdb heap allocation fail crash

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am monitoring hyperledger fabric couchdb and sometimes the couchdb 
 docker container stoped by heap allocation failing.

below is the logs right before couchdb docker container stoped. 
The server host spec is AWS t2.micro and the fabric network consists of 1 peer(dev-mode), 1orderer, 1cli, 1ca, 1couchdb and 1ccenv container.

I have no idea what is the reason and how to solve this problem.

`[info] 2018-11-06T14:19:19.839617Z nonode@nohost <0.19858.2908> -------- Closing index for db: shards/80000000-9fffffff/my-fabric.1533697140 idx: _design/16c2f95e8309df9a6f993586266150ba639ba7e8 sig: "97b910c8bbd4a195d0813dc30b7f0b91" because normal
[info] 2018-11-06T14:19:19.844610Z nonode@nohost <0.12086.2908> -------- Index shutdown by monitor notice for db: shards/80000000-9fffffff/_replicator.1533696646 idx: _design/_replicator
[info] 2018-11-06T14:19:19.847820Z nonode@nohost <0.12086.2908> -------- Closing index for db: shards/80000000-9fffffff/_replicator.1533696646 idx: _design/_replicator sig: "3e823c2a4383ac0c18d4e574135a5b08" because normal
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 212907632 bytes of memory (of type "heap").
[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed`

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you fix this and what caused it?

Comment: Hi @MYil What machine do you use for hyperledger fabric. I sovled the issue by changing machine to t2.medium. Check couchdb hardware requirement at https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/pre-install.html